# How AggregateRoots aggregate diffident object types?

Tags: design-patterns, domain-driven-design, cqrs, aggregateroot

Let’s say we have *Foo* as an AggregateRoot. And there are generic *Foo*s as well as *EnhancedFoo*s with a number of extended properties. Is it OK to expose “Actions” on a single aggregate root class for generic and enhanced properties and have validation check to throw exception if enhanced action was called on non-enhanced *Foo* object? Technically, AggregateRoot in this case will aggregate all possible “Actions” for all supported *Foo* types?

Obviously a lot depends on domain structure, but I think this hypothetical situation is quite common. Probably basic question but I'm just starting with Aggregates/Roots.

**Update per feedback**

Let’s say we have *Foo* as an AggregateRoot. And there are generic *Foo*s as well as *FlyableFoo*s, *SwimmableFoo*s, etc. So, Aggregate should "know" about all possible behaviors (fly, quack, swim) and expose it appropriately to Service functionality. And if something is called some reason that is not “supported” by current object, Aggregate may throw an exception “Sorry, penguin can’t fly”.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that this is a good idea. You should try to keep a clean code at the same time you use the DDD approach. So, I recommend you to respect the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles when coding the Aggregates and try to [favor composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance).

Also, when designing Aggregates, you should not think about `properties` but state and behavior. This is more important in CQRS as you don't query the Aggregates, you don't have any getters (and according to DDD you don't have any setters as well as you should name your methods according to the ubiquitous language).

You could use inheritance but you must be sure that the gain (code reuse) is greater than what you loose (increased cognitive effort). I don't recommend it.

> And if something is called some reason that is not “supported” by current object, Aggregate may throw an exception “Sorry, penguin can’t fly”.

This would break the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle).

Comment: It is not clear from my question, but I actually do use composition. Also instead saying “Properties” I should have said “Behaviors”. I added update to my question, please check. Also, thank you for mentioning “Composition over inheritance” diagram, it was very helpful!